# why is it that my USB port charges my iPhone in Windows, but not Ubuntu?

Tags: usb, iphone

Why does my USB port charge my iPhone in Windows 10, but not Ubuntu 16.04?

I am not asking how to change this or fix it, I just want to understand how it is possible. One would think that hardware is hardware.

It is a dual-boot Dell Optiplex 755 desktop machine running up-to-date versions of Windows 10 Pro and Ubuntu 16.04 . It has several external HDDs attached via USB.

I recall that under 14.04, this same USB port could charge the iPhone.